# iOS call buttons action through the button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call the action which is connected to a button through the button it self. Can this be done? To clarify my point this is want I mean:

```
[self.button callIBAction:self]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the event that triggers the button, for example:

```
[self.button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Or, if you are in the same view controller that implements the action:

```
[self callIBAction:self.button]
```

Comment: Done had to wait a bit ;)

Comment: can we call these methods in viewDidLoad ?

Answer (score -1):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourIBAction:) withObject:nil];
```